# Как вернуть суму чисел массива

Tags: javascript, массивы

Мне нужно чтобы функция принимала числа, и возвращать сумму элементов массива. Функция должна возвращать null если в качестве аргумента передан не маcсив. Мой код сейчас выглядит вот так. Почему он не работает?

```js
function getSum(arr) {
  let sum = 0;
  for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    if(Array.isArray[i]){
      return sum + arr[i];
    } else{
      return null;
    }
  }
}

// examples
getSum([1, 10, -10, 4]); // ==> 5
getSum([1]); // ==> 1
getSum([-8, 8]); // ==> 0
getSum(10, 12, 14); // ==> null
```

Comment: Что значит "не работает"?

Comment: что ты имеешь в виду когда пишешь "не работает"?

Comment: у меня заданые значения не выводяться

Comment: продись по каждому числу и прибавь значения

Answer (score 2):

Пример

```js
function getSum(arr) {
  if (!Array.isArray(arr)) return null;  
  return arr.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0)
}

// examples
console.log(getSum([1, 10, -10, 4])) // ==> 5
console.log(getSum([1])); // ==> 1
console.log(getSum([-8, 8])); // ==> 0
console.log(getSum(10, 12, 14)); // ==> null
```

Comment: проверку лучше делать **до** цикла, в противном случае результат может быть непредсказуем.

Comment: @Grundy - спасибо, уже понял

Comment: пример немного неудачный был в комментарии. Цикл бы выполнился, но в принципе результат верный бы был

Answer (score 1):

Код работает, просто выполняет другую задачу, а именно: возвращает первый элемент массива приведенный к числу, в случае, если элемент является массивом, либо `null` в противном случае.

Для решения исходной задачи - проверка должна осуществляться **до** цикла

[`Array.isArray`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray) - это метод, следовательно для вызова нужно указывать круглые скобки, а не квадратные, также проверять надо параметр `arr`: `Array.isArray(arr)`

В теле цикла достаточно прибавлять значения в переменную `sum`: `sum += arr[i]`

Результат нужно вернуть **после** цикла. Результат содержится в переменной `sum`: `return sum`.

```js
function getSum(arr) {
  if (!Array.isArray(arr)) return null;

  let sum = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    sum += arr[i];
  }
  return sum;
}

// examples
console.log(getSum([1, 10, -10, 4])); // ==> 5
console.log(getSum([1])); // ==> 1
console.log(getSum([-8, 8])); // ==> 0
console.log(getSum(10, 12, 14)); // ==> null
```

Comment: спасибо, подскажите а почему вы ставите в начале (!Array.isArray(arr)) знак "!", я просто новичок и еще плохо ориентируюсь в таких значениях

Comment: @ЯнаКоваль ! означает "не". Проверка ```Array.isArray(arr)``` возвращает ```true``` если переменная ```arr``` является массивом. В примере, код блока ```if``` выполнится если ```arr``` НЕ (```!```) является массивом. Если бы восклицательного знака не было, код блока ```if``` выполнился бы, если arr - массив

Answer (score 0):

```js
function getSum(arr) {  
  if (!Array.isArray(arr))
    return null;

  let sum = 0;

  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    sum += arr[i];
  }

  return sum;
}

// examples
console.log(getSum([1, 10, -10, 4])); // ==> 5
console.log(getSum([1])); // ==> 1
console.log(getSum([-8, 8])); // ==> 0
console.log(getSum(10, 12, 14)); // ==> null
```